How to create a multi-column custom visual transform?
In our ETL process we are building out a pipeline where someones takes input files (ex. csv) and maps the columns to existing column names in our DB. After the mapping is complete a glue workflow will perform all of the needed data post processing and eventually loading the data into our database. We will be ingesting 3k+ data sources. Each of them will use the same workflow after data mapping is complete.
The "Change Schema" widget almost works as intended. The only hangup is that the "Target key" value is a manual input. Ideally this would be a populated list containing column names from our database but can alternatively be a static list that we update as the schema changes.
Is it possible to create a multi column custom visual transform similar to Change Schema where I can specify a static dropdown list?
I have tried to create a multi-column custom visual transform similar to Change Schema. I cannot find any information on how to create a multi-column visual transform. If there's a minimal example of how to do this I'll be able to achieve the desired result.
